# Symfony get list of required PHP modules

Tags: php, symfony, deployment

When deploying a Symfony application to another server I often need to wait for the `composer install` or `cache:clear` in order to know if a required **PHP module** is installed.

E.g.

```
 // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug false                                             


In Imagine.php line 172:

  Gd not installed
```

And so I have to run (or ask to the system engineer to run) `sudo apt-get install php-gd`.

Is there a way to **know this list before deploying** the application?

Something like:

`php bin/console debug:php-modules`

*P.S. I would like to know a solution without using Docker.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run [`composer check-platform-reqs`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#check-platform-reqs) after `composer install` and it will tell you if an extension is missing.

> The check-platform-reqs command checks that your PHP and extensions versions match the platform requirements of the installed packages. This can be used to verify that a production server has all the extensions needed to run a project after installing it for example.

Although, from your question I assume you are using [Imagine](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library which by looking at [it's composer.json](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine/blob/master/composer.json) **does not require any PHP extensions**, they are actually listed as suggestions and you have to install them manually.

```
"suggest": {
    "ext-gd": "to use the GD implementation",
    "ext-imagick": "to use the Imagick implementation",
    "ext-gmagick": "to use the Gmagick implementation"
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I also used `composer suggests --no-dev | grep '-ext'` to get suggested extensions but I don't think I can output which extensions I have installed in my dev machine, right?

Comment: You can with `php -m`

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs a PHP extension, you should put it in `composer.json`:

```
{
    …
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        …
```

It will:

1. prevent installing the project if a module is missing in any environment
2. give you a reference documentation to know what modules are required

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you install all module at once, here is the list:

`php7.2            php7.2-enchant    php7.2-mbstring   php7.2-snmp
php7.2-bcmath     php7.2-fpm        php7.2-mysql      php7.2-soap
php7.2-bz2        php7.2-gd         php7.2-odbc       php7.2-sqlite3
php7.2-cgi        php7.2-gmp        php7.2-opcache    php7.2-sybase
php7.2-cli        php7.2-imap       php7.2-pgsql      php7.2-tidy
php7.2-common     php7.2-interbase  php7.2-phpdbg     php7.2-xml
php7.2-curl       php7.2-intl       php7.2-pspell     php7.2-xmlrpc
php7.2-dba        php7.2-json       php7.2-readline   php7.2-xsl
php7.2-dev        php7.2-ldap       php7.2-recode     php7.2-zip`

Comment: In another project I needed php-imagick which is not listed. Does installing all these modules have performance issues?

Comment: @StockBreak well,i don't think this can be a performance issues.

Comment: install just what you need